# Wicks of Menorah after Chanukah

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, menora-chanukia

Where is the source of the Minhag to burn the oil, wicks of the menorah/Chanukiya after Chanukah?

Answer (score 3):

Abudarham quoting the Sheiltot and Geonim

> מנין הפתילות של שמונת ימי חנוכה שש ושלשים סימן להם ל"ו חכמו. וכתוב בשאלתות דרב אחאי נר חנוכה שהותיר בה שמן מהו צריך לעשות בו, תש' דת"ר נר חנוכה שהותיר בה שמן ביום ראשון מוסיף עליו ומדליקו ביו' ב' ביום השני מוסיף עליו ומדליקו ביום השלישי וכן בשאר הימים אבל אם הותיר ביום השמיני **עושה לו מדורה ושורפו בפני עצמו** כיון **שהוקצה למצוה אסור להשתמש ממנו**. וכן כתבו הגאונים שהשמן והפתילות אסור להשתמש בהן אחר שכבו דאיתקצו למצוה.
>
> והקשה הרב ר' גרשום בר' שלמה דהא קיימא לן דתשמישי מצוה נזרקין. ותירץ דהני מיירי כגון תשמיש שופר ולולב וכיוצא בהן שדעתו עליהן אחר מצותן שיודע שישארו אחרי כן אבל הני אין דעתו עליהן כסבור שישרפו בשעת מצותן. אי נמי שוינהו רבנן כתשמישי קדושה מפני שהוא זכר לשמן של הקדש,
>
> ויש לשאול אם כן פתילות של שבת ישרפו לדעת זו, ויש לומר דלא דמו אהדדי דנר שבת עיקר מצותו ליהנות ולהשתמש לאורו על השלחן ולכל הבית וכיון שכן יכול ליהנות אחר מצותן מה שאין כן בנר חנוכה שעיקר מצותו משום פרסומי ניסא ולא להשתמש
> לאורה ומשום הכי אסורין בהנאה אחר מצותן כי לכך נעשו מתחלה

Because Oil and Wick fulfill 3 conditions: reserved for the use of Mitsva and there is a prohibition to use them at the time of the Mitsva for  any else profit,  when he started the mitsva he thought there would be none left after the Mitsva, if something rest it is accidentally. This is different from Shofar or Lulav they allways rest after the Mitsva and it's allowed to think before the mitsva that he will use them for something else, and from  a Shabbat Candel's Oil and Wick that is made in way to take a profit (from the light) at the time of the Mitsva.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in @kouty answer there is an early source for burning the wicks and oil  . Just to add the Shulchan Aruch 677:4 codifies this as well. The sefer Shu"t Hashoel volume 3 page 202 brings many answers to the question whether one can throw them into the garbage or rather needs to be specifically burned . It seems that most Poskim hold it should be burned but there may be some leniency (see it inside ).

Rav Yosef Messas in his sefer Ner Mitzvah he brings the minhag of Menkes(Morroco)which took place on the 9th day of chanukka(interesting way of describing it). They called the day yom hashemesh and would make a whole production to burn it and would say a short prayer while burning  the oil and wicks.

Comment: Shulchan Aruch does not say to burn the wicks